# Using WDI API in R: Data Issues

Tags: r

```
library(WDI)
library(calibrate)

WDIsearch("life expectancy")
#SP.DYN.LE00.IN

WDIsearch("population, total")
#SP.POP.TOTL

WDIsearch("GDP per capita")
#NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.CD

gapmind <- WDI(country="all", indicator = c("SP.DYN.LE00.IN", "SP.POP.TOTL", "NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.CD"), start=2015, end=2015, extra=TRUE)
```

When I print gapmind, under SP.DYN.LE00.IN, there is all NA for 2015. I know that the API is update though, so why won't my data frame pick this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the URL that `WDI` uses to get data, and there's missing data for 2015, at least for Afghanistan (haven't tried anywhere else). Note the empty  tag:

```
http://api.worldbank.org/countries/AFG/indicators/SP.DYN.LE00.IN?date=2015:2015

<wb:data page="1" pages="1" per_page="50" total="1">
 <wb:data>
  <wb:indicator id="SP.DYN.LE00.IN">Life expectancy at birth, total (years)</wb:indicator>
   <wb:country id="AF">Afghanistan</wb:country>
   <wb:date>2015</wb:date>
   <wb:value/>
   <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
 </wb:data> 
</wb:data>
```

If you can find data for 2015 on the WDI web site or API then the WDI package is looking in the wrong place.

The maps for that indicator only seem to go to 2014:

```
http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.DYN.LE00.IN?view=map
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused then, because everyone else in my class seems to have it.